# PHP - MYSQLI - UPDATE DATABASE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want users to UPDATE any field(s) they want in d database - table but I don't want the UPDATE .. SET to erase existing records with empty submission if they submit without changing all the fields.. but changed only the ones they want to..

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET username = '$username', email = '$email',
fname = '$fname', lname = '$lname', address = '$address', city = '$city',
country = '$country', phone = '$phone', aboutme = '$aboutme' WHERE email = '$email'";
```

If the user only updates address and phone then submits his entry.. this instruction erases other fields that is not filled in the form.... I don't want that to happen. Kindly look into this. Thanks

Please I have tried your suggestion but its not working for me.. may I am doing something wrong -- I am new to PHP - Here is my code below:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user_profile SET ";
if ($username!="")
$sql ."username = '$username',"

if ($fname!="")
$sql ."fname = '$fname',"

if ($lname!="")
$sql ."lname = '$lname',"

if ($address!="")
$sql ."address = '$address',"

if ($city!="")
$sql ."city = '$city',"

if($country!="") 
$sql ."country = '$country', "

if($phone!="")
$sql ."phone = '$phone', "

if($aboutme!="")
$sql ."aboutme = '$aboutme' "

$sql ."WHERE email = '$email'";

$query = mysqli_query($database,$sql);
if($query)
{
     $message = "<div class=\"btn btn-lg btn-default\"><i class=\"text-success text-center\">Update Successful!</i></div>";
    //echo "update successful";
}
```

Comment: If they are updating information, what about having the form populated with whatever is already stored in the database. That way no empty values are passed through and the user doesn't have to fill in everything in the form again that they don't want to update

Comment: @AndrewNolan Exactly; which is what I have used in the past and had in mind for this question. +1

Answer (score 2):

You should be using parameters rather than placing user input directly into strings.  However, that is good practice and protects against SQL injection and poorly formed parameters.

Doesn't help your problem, though.  You need to see if there is a new value, otherwise, use the old one.  Assuming the new value is `NULL` when not present, then use `COALESCE()`.  For example:

```
SET username = COALESCE($username, username),
    . . .
```

Note:  There is no reason to set `email` in the `SET` statement because you are using it in the `WHERE`.

Comment: *"There is no reason to set email in the SET statement because you are using it in the WHERE"* - A good point Gordon, yet what if the email does need to be changed? It's indeed an option and may be what their code is supposed to do.

Comment: Since you have `$username` in quotes, it will never be `NULL`. If the PHP variable is null, you'll create an empty string in the SQL.

Comment: thanks all but I am new to PHP I really need a way out - cos I have a project to deliver.. I didnt understand what you mean